# Get image item-id with rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list with a column of images, I want to get the item-id of the image using the sharepoint rest api.
My query is the following

[https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testsharepoint/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('autopartes')/items?$select=Icon](https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testsharepoint/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27autopartes%27)/items?$select=Icon)

the answer is the following

> "Icon": "{"type":"thumbnail","fileName":"llanta4.png","nativeFile":{},"fieldName":"Icon","serverUrl":"https://mysite.sharepoint.com","fieldId":"9fd8e3af-a92b-4d5c-a404-7b292186c4c9","serverRelativeUrl":"/sites/testsharepoint/SiteAssets/Lists/511gec72-2j1d-4134-b8f5-af1b9b4a0b2e/llantas%204.png","id":"e2961753-92e4-1142-84a7-b6605305e0cf"}"

I am looking for an item-id similiar to this
id: 01365ALXG6CG6NXQHGAGTJLKAS7CSG72XT

I understand that this id is provided by onedrive but I don't know If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much thanks

Comment: I don't think you will be able to fetch it using REST API from [SharePoint image columns](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/). Can you explain the need of fetching the ID you mentioned? For what you will be using this? Maybe we can suggest another approach to achieve your requirements.

Comment: I need that url to query it to get the `@content.downloadUrl` element: which contains the public image and display it in my React Js app @GaneshSanap